# iOS 11 Safari webapp status bar styling adds bar below body and html

Tags: html, mobile-safari, ios11

With the following meta tags set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

and following style:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
}
```

If started in full screen, the status bar is transparent with white text, and the viewport starts at the top of the screen, *but it ends above the bottom of the screen*. The height of the bar on the bottom is much the same as the hight of the status bar would be. The interesting part is that this bar has the same background color as the body, but it is not part of the body, as adding a border to the body shows that it ends above this bar. I can position anything in the area of the original status bar, but nothing in this bar at the bottom. It looks that the bottom bar background is not always set to the body background by default, only when I also set the border color for the body.

If I change `black-translucent` to `black`, everything looks as expected: black status bar, and the viewport is from beneath the status bar till the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Can the `black-translucent` be made to work properly on iOS 11?

PS: I am developing on Windows, thus no WebInspector is available to me.